# MySQL comment table structure question

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to add comments and replies to comments to my website for my members but I was wondering how would my mysql tables look like for my comments and replies to comments? Can someone give me some examples thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: [mysql structure for comments and comment replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260878/mysql-structure-for-comments-and-comment-replies)