# PHP search function clarification

Tags: php, wordpress

I found this function in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260878/mysql-structure-for-comments-and-comment-replies) on Stack Overflow, but I would like a clarification on something:

```
function sort_comments($ar)
{
    $comments = array();
    foreach($ar as $item)
    {
        if(is_null($item['parent_id'])) $comments[] = $item;
        else 
        {
                $parent_array = array_search_key($item['parent_id'],$comments,'id');
                if($parent_array !== false) $comments[$parent_array]['replies'][] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

Could someone explain the arguments passed to array_searched_key() ? I searched for this function in php.net but did not find it. Again, I'm a bit confused about the arguments, specially why the $comment array is passed to it.

Comment: i would to use recursion here instead

Comment: Is this in WordPress, I think it is, but would be nice if you could confirm.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a PHP core function. It's a Wordpress function built specialy to sort comment when displaying them.

But there's a simple explanations as I understand it:

```
First argument: the ID to search (the query)
Second argument: array to search in (the datas)
Third argument: the column to search in (in the array)
```

As I understand it, it's this.

Answer (score 0):

If you linked the relevant StackOverflow thread it would put things in context. My guess is that it's [this implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#99203), or similar. The function is not native to PHP and without knowing it's source it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the WordPress function being used in this case - the only place I can find this function in the [WordPress codebase](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/cbpress/trunk/lib/class.fn.php) only accepts two parameters.

I rather think that they are referring to this other function I found on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/arCgJTXg). Unfortunately, the author hasn't provided comments describing the parameters but we have:

```
$needle - a value to match inside the array of arrays being searched 
$haystack - an array of arrays being searched 
$haystackKey - the key within the inner arrays which we want to find in the array of arrays
$strict - if set to true (default false) then type matching is enforced
```

So, the function returns true if the key and data pair can be located in at least one of the inner arrays, and false if not.