# PHP query join to get comment replies

Tags: php, mysql, join, comments

I know that there are other posts out there like this, I've been using them. I've got three tables:

```
users_info
  user_id | user_name

blog_comments
  comment_id | comment

blog_reply
  user_id | comment_id | reply | reply_date
```

I'm trying to join the tables to get user_name from users_info and to return blog_reply by blog_comments.comment_id

I've been using:
[mysql structure for comments and comment replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260878/mysql-structure-for-comments-and-comment-replies)

I'm stuck on the table joins, any help is much appreciated.

```
    $get_replies = ("SELECT
                      blog_reply.user_id,
                      blog_reply.comment_id,
                      blog_reply.reply,
                      blog_reply.reply_date,
                      users_info.user_name AS user_name
                    FROM blog_reply
                    JOIN users_info ON blog_reply.user_id = users_info.user_id
                    LEFT JOIN blog_comments ON blog_reply.comment_id = blog_reply.comment_id
                    JOIN users_info ON blog_reply.user_id = users_info.user_id
                    WHERE blog_comments.comment_id = '{$comment_id}'
                    ORDER BY blog_reply.reply_date DESC");

    $reply = mysql_query($get_replies);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple MySQL things:

1. If you don't need the table don't join it. You don't need any data out of the blog_comments table so you shouldn't include it in your query. Since the blog_reply table has the comment_id you can just use that table
2. You don't need to do users_info.user_name AS user_name. That's redundant.
3. You can add the where clause to the join.

Here is how I would write the MySQL statement:

```
SELECT
    blog_reply.user_id,
    blog_reply.comment_id,
    blog_reply.reply,
    blog_reply.reply_date,
    users_info.user_name
FROM 
    blog_reply
JOIN 
    users_info 
ON 
    blog_reply.user_id = users_info.user_id AND
    blog_reply.comment_id = '{$comment_id}'
ORDER BY 
    blog_reply.reply_date DESC
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: yes thanks that helps. Yeah you're right about that not needed table, I think it's left over from trying to get comments and replies at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
FROM blog_reply
JOIN users_info ON blog_reply.user_id = users_info.user_id
JOIN blog_comments ON blog_reply.comment_id = blog_comments.comment_id
WHERE blog_comments.comment_id = '{$comment_id}'
```